# custom array-like object looks like true array

Tags: javascript

I have custom array-like object, with all the array methods, which acts as an array, but `Object.prototype.toString.call(myArrayLikeObj)` returns `[object Object]` not `[object Array]`

How to prepare my object to return `[object Array]`?

Can I see somewhere `Object.toString` source code?

Comment: *How to prepare my object to return [object Array]?* If it's not an actual, native array, it shouldn claim to be.

Comment: You could simply overwrite the [`toString`](//developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/toString) method or use `Symbol.toStringTag` as below. Note that if there is no actual inheritance going on, then `yourObject instanceof Array` will still be `false`. See [`extends`](//developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes/extends) and [`Symbol.species`](//developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Symbol/species). I don’t see what the benefit of doing anything other than `class extends Array` is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`Symbol.toStringTag`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Symbol/toStringTag) is the well-known name of the "tag" you want:

```js
YourCustomArrayPrototype[Symbol.toStringTag] = () => 'Array'; // Sure, why not?
```

That said, if you `extend` `Array` you will get this *for free*:

```
class MyCustomArray extends Array {}

console.log(
  Object.prototype.toString.call(new MyCustomArray(3))
); // Logs [object Array]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can give the object a `Symbol.toStringTag` property if you want.

```js
const myArrayLikeObj = {
  [Symbol.toStringTag]: 'Array',
}
console.log(Object.prototype.toString.call(myArrayLikeObj));
```

Alternatively, you can extend `Array` and it'll be done for you.

```js
class MyArray extends Array {};
const myArrayLikeObj = new MyArray();
console.log(Object.prototype.toString.call(myArrayLikeObj));
```